# Видимость переменной после if

Tags: python, if

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу.

```
info_9 = kont_info.find(class_="section__info_sl").get_text(strip=True)  
kont_info = soup.find_all(class_="blockInfo__section_sl section")[14]
info_7 = kont_info.find(class_="section__title_sl").get_text(strip=True)
if info_7 == "Телефон":
    info_71 = kont_info.find(class_="section__info_sl").get_text(strip=True)
```

При создании словаря переменная info_71 не определяется. Как я полагаю, переменная info_71 в дальнейшем не определяется из-за if-а. Не могли бы подсказать, как сделать так, чтобы переменная info_71 отображалась только при наличии в блоке info_7 слова "Телефон".

Comment: Что значит «не определяется», где и когда не определяется и при чём тут json?

Comment: `info_7` должно быть именно `Телефон` или содержать его?

Comment: То есть вы хотите сравнить переменную `info_7` со словом "Телефон" не на равенство, а на наличие подстроки? "...только при *наличии* в блоке...".

Comment: Во втором случае используйте `if 'телефон' in info_7.lower():`

Comment: А чтобы ошибки не было, проинициализируйте `info_71` заранее, например, приравняйте его к `''`

Comment: Должно быть именно "Телефон" и важно именно наличие этого слова для того чтобы был спарсен info_71.

Comment: тогда так `if 'Телефон' in info_7`

Comment: Только остался один нюанс, info_71 не желает определяться в словаре...

Comment: Как я описал выше, вероятно (так как я не вижу весь ваш код) у вас `info_71` в контексте программы не существует, проверяйте или просто заранее проинициализируйте её пустой строкой

Comment: Спасибо за совет!

Comment: Это как-то странно, что вы всё время говорите про какой-то словарь, а в коде его нет. Если словарь важен, добавьте код с ним. А если не важен, то уберите его из вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из комментариев я сформировал для вас ответ.
Используйте конструкцию `in` для поиска подстроки в строке.

```
info_9 = kont_info.find(class_="section__info_sl").get_text(strip=True)  
kont_info = soup.find_all(class_="blockInfo__section_sl section")[14]
info_7 = kont_info.find(class_="section__title_sl").get_text(strip=True)

if 'Телефон' in info_7: # вот здесь мы поменяли условие
    info_71 = kont_info.find(class_="section__info_sl").get_text(strip=True)
```

А для того, чтобы не было проблем с отсутствием переменной `info_71`, вы можете проинициализировать её заранее.

```
info_9 = kont_info.find(class_="section__info_sl").get_text(strip=True)  
kont_info = soup.find_all(class_="blockInfo__section_sl section")[14]
info_7 = kont_info.find(class_="section__title_sl").get_text(strip=True)
info_71 = '' # вот здесь мы задали переменную пустой строкой
if 'Телефон' in info_7: 
    info_71 = kont_info.find(class_="section__info_sl").get_text(strip=True)
```

Comment: Если мой ответ помог вам, **не стесняйтесь пометить его как решение галочкой** слева от ответа

Comment: И добро пожаловать на ruSO!!